# Pending Intent types and the Alarm Manager

Tags: android, android-intent, alarmmanager

I would like to set an alarm that will fire off once.

There is a pendingintent flag named OneShot. It looks like that would be the right flag to use.

But do I need to use that flag? If I use AlarmManager.SetTime(), then it should not repeat.

What does OneShot offer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're asking the difference between scheduling an alarm one time, via [AlarmManager.set](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#set%28int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29) (not setTime?) and the use of [PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#FLAG_ONE_SHOT).

First understand that a `PendingIntent` is a license to act as your app with your apps perms at some point in the future. From the PI docs: "The returned object can be handed to other applications so that they can perform the action you described on your behalf at a later time."

If you just use `AlarmManager.set` ONCE, then yes, your `PendingIntent` will only be *fired* once, but whatever captures it can use it more than once, unless you send it with a "one shot" flag. Now, if "whatever captures it" is also your own app, then it's probably not a big deal (you are unlikely to abuse your own future self ;)). Still, if it's a `PendingIntent` that you think should only ever be used once, it's probably just safer to go ahead and use the one shot flag anyway.

To sum up the difference, setting `FLAG_ONE_SHOT` sends the permissions to use the PI only once *with* the PI, versus only firing it off once with `AlarmManager`. How many times you fire the alarm, and what the permissions of the PI are, are two different things.

Comment: Thanks.  It is getting clearer.  Using FLAG_ONE_SHOT will keep me honest later.

Comment: I do have a question about Set vs SetTime.  According to this page http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html.  Set will Schedule an alarm.  Which sounds like what I want.  SetTime sets the system wall clock time.  I am less sure what that means.  Is setTime relevant for me?

Comment: "setTime" just actually sets the system wall clock time, which means not the "elapsed" time since the device has started, but the system clock time. Very often in Android you'll use the elapsed time for counters and such since the system time can vary and be reset. See SystemClock for more info on "wall time": http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html. Anyway, yeah, to schedule an alarm you definitely want set, setRepeating, etc (and not setTime).